# PyTorch error when running PyTorch image on Kubernetes

Tags: python, pytorch, airflow, torchvision

I have a Docker image that uses PyTorch to perform object detection.
The container runs fine on **local** and on **Google Colab**, however when running on **Kubernetes** (through **Airflow**) it raises the following error:

```
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,592] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,592] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/main.py", line 5, in <module>
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     app()
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/typer/main.py", line 214, in __call__
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return get_command(self)(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,594] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,595] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return callback(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,596] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/typer/main.py", line 497, in wrapper
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,596] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,596] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/app/__init__.py", line 52, in detect_from_file
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     coco_path=coco_path,
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/app/__init__.py", line 126, in _detect_from_file
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     tables = infer_page(page_filename, model)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/app/utils.py", line 9, in infer_page
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     result = inference_detector(model, str(img))
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,597] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/apis/inference.py", line 86, in inference_detector
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,598] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     result = model(return_loss=False, rescale=True, **data)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,598] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,598] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,598] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/core/fp16/decorators.py", line 49, in new_func
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,598] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return old_func(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,599] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/base.py", line 149, in forward
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,599] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return self.forward_test(img, img_metas, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,599] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/base.py", line 130, in forward_test
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,599] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return self.simple_test(imgs[0], img_metas[0], **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,599] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/cascade_rcnn.py", line 324, in simple_test
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     self.test_cfg.rpn) if proposals is None else proposals
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/detectors/test_mixins.py", line 34, in simple_test_rpn
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     proposal_list = self.rpn_head.get_bboxes(*proposal_inputs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/core/fp16/decorators.py", line 127, in new_func
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     return old_func(*args, **kwargs)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/anchor_heads/anchor_head.py", line 276, in get_bboxes
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,600] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     scale_factor, cfg, rescale)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,601] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/models/anchor_heads/rpn_head.py", line 92, in get_bboxes_single
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,601] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     proposals, _ = nms(proposals, cfg.nms_thr)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,601] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -   File "/content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_wrapper.py", line 54, in nms
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,601] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO -     inds = nms_cuda.nms(dets_th, iou_thr)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - RuntimeError: CUDA error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device (launch_kernel at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loops.cuh:103)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string const&) + 0x33 (0x7faf44434193 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #1: void at::native::gpu_index_kernel<__nv_dl_wrapper_t<__nv_dl_tag<void (*)(at::TensorIterator&, c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::ArrayRef<long>), &(void at::native::index_kernel_impl<at::native::OpaqueType<8> >(at::TensorIterator&, c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::ArrayRef<long>)), 1u>> >(at::TensorIterator&, c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::ArrayRef<long>, __nv_dl_wrapper_t<__nv_dl_tag<void (*)(at::TensorIterator&, c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::ArrayRef<long>), &(void at::native::index_kernel_impl<at::native::OpaqueType<8> >(at::TensorIterator&, c10::ArrayRef<long>, c10::ArrayRef<long>)), 1u>> const&) + 0x7bb (0x7faefc45e87b in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #2: <unknown function> + 0x580fc32 (0x7faefc458c32 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #3: <unknown function> + 0x580ff88 (0x7faefc458f88 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,602] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #4: <unknown function> + 0x1a7493b (0x7faef86bd93b in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,603] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #5: at::native::index(at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) + 0x47e (0x7faef86b96fe in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,603] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #6: <unknown function> + 0x1fe06aa (0x7faef8c296aa in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,603] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #7: <unknown function> + 0x1fe5173 (0x7faef8c2e173 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,603] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #8: <unknown function> + 0x3bffe6a (0x7faefa848e6a in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #9: <unknown function> + 0x1fe5173 (0x7faef8c2e173 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib/libtorch.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #10: at::Tensor c10::KernelFunction::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const + 0xa3 (0x7faef3b7ec73 in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #11: c10::Dispatcher::doCallUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::DispatchTable const&, c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > > const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&)#1}::operator()(ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&) const + 0xc9 (0x7faef3b7c331 in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #12: std::result_of<c10::Dispatcher::doCallUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::DispatchTable const&, c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > > const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&)#1} (ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&)>::type c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > >::read<c10::Dispatcher::doCallUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::DispatchTable const&, c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > > const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&)#1}>(c10::Dispatcher::doCallUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::DispatchTable const&, c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > > const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > const&)#1}&&) const + 0x128 (0x7faef3b7eed2 in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #13: at::Tensor c10::Dispatcher::doCallUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::DispatchTable const&, c10::LeftRight<ska::flat_hash_map<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction, std::hash<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::equal_to<c10::TensorTypeId>, std::allocator<std::pair<c10::TensorTypeId, c10::KernelFunction> > > > const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const + 0x6a (0x7faef3b7c3ba in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #14: c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}::operator()(c10::DispatchTable const&) const + 0x80 (0x7faef3b7936a in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #15: std::result_of<c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1} (c10::DispatchTable const&)>::type c10::LeftRight<c10::DispatchTable>::read<c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}>(c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}&&) const + 0x128 (0x7faef3b7f056 in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #16: c10::guts::infer_function_traits<c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}>::type::return_type c10::impl::OperatorEntry::readDispatchTable<c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}>(c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const::{lambda(c10::DispatchTable const&)#1}&&) const + 0x4a (0x7faef3b7c42c in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,604] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #17: at::Tensor c10::Dispatcher::callUnboxedOnly<at::Tensor, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor> >(c10::OperatorHandle const&, at::Tensor const&, c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const + 0x7c (0x7faef3b7941a in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,605] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #18: at::Tensor::index(c10::ArrayRef<at::Tensor>) const + 0x16f (0x7faef3b74dad in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,605] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #19: nms_cuda(at::Tensor, float) + 0x84f (0x7faef3b71a0c in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,605] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #20: nms(at::Tensor const&, float) + 0xee (0x7faef3b6087e in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,605] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #21: <unknown function> + 0x335ab (0x7faef3b6f5ab in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
[2021-06-23 07:13:17,605] {pod_launcher.py:148} INFO - frame #22: <unknown function> + 0x302b0 (0x7faef3b6c2b0 in /content/mmdetection/mmdet/ops/nms/nms_cuda.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Following is the output of the command `nvidia-smi` and another util of `mmdetection` ran on both Kubernetes and Google Colab (where the code runs just fine)

### **output running the container on Kubernetes**

- `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000001:00:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   23C    P0    26W / 250W |      0MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- `python3 /content/mmdetection/mmdet/utils/collect_env.py`

```
sys.platform: linux
Python: 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00) [GCC 8.4.0]
CUDA available: True
CUDA_HOME: /usr/local/cuda
NVCC: Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
GPU 0: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB
GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
PyTorch: 1.4.0+cu100
PyTorch compiling details: PyTorch built with:
  - GCC 7.3
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.4 Product Build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v0.21.1 (Git Hash 7d2fd500bc78936d1d648ca713b901012f470dbc)
  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)
  - NNPACK is enabled
  - CUDA Runtime 10.0
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 7.6.3
  - Magma 2.5.1
  - Build settings: BLAS=MKL, BUILD_NAMEDTENSOR=OFF, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CXX_FLAGS= -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Wno-stringop-overflow, DISABLE_NUMA=1, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_STATIC_DISPATCH=OFF,

TorchVision: 0.5.0+cu100
OpenCV: 4.5.2
MMCV: 0.4.3
MMDetection: 1.2.0+unknown
MMDetection Compiler: GCC 7.5
MMDetection CUDA Compiler: 10.0
```

### **output running the code on Google Colab**

- `nvidia-smi`

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.27       Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   37C    P0    25W / 300W |      0MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

- `python3 /content/mmdetection/mmdet/utils/collect_env.py`

```
sys.platform: linux
Python: 3.7.10 (default, May  3 2021, 02:48:31) [GCC 7.5.0]
CUDA available: True
CUDA_HOME: /usr/local/cuda
NVCC: Build cuda_11.0_bu.TC445_37.28845127_0
GPU 0: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB
GCC: gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
PyTorch: 1.4.0+cu100
PyTorch compiling details: PyTorch built with:
  - GCC 7.3
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2019.0.4 Product Build 20190411 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v0.21.1 (Git Hash 7d2fd500bc78936d1d648ca713b901012f470dbc)
  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)
  - NNPACK is enabled
  - CUDA Runtime 10.0
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 7.6.3
  - Magma 2.5.1
  - Build settings: BLAS=MKL, BUILD_NAMEDTENSOR=OFF, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CXX_FLAGS= -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fopenmp -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Wno-stringop-overflow, DISABLE_NUMA=1, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_STATIC_DISPATCH=OFF, 

TorchVision: 0.5.0+cu100
OpenCV: 4.5.2
MMCV: 0.4.3
MMDetection: 1.2.0+0f33c08
MMDetection Compiler: GCC 7.5
MMDetection CUDA Compiler: 11.0
```

**Note:** the output posted here for Google Colab was running on a Tesla V100 GPU, however sometimes I get allocated a Tesla P100 (which is the same GPU used on Kubernetes) and the code runs smoothly on both cases (on Google Colab) however it raises the error when running on Kubernetes.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Does you pods have assigned GPU? How do you ran you task, as KubernetePodOperator or on Airflow workers? Seeing [that others had this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/31285) also I would say it's not Airflow specific.

Comment: The version of whatever it is you are running has not been built with support for your GPU

Comment: @TomaszUrbaszek, yes the pods have assigned GPU (a combination of toleration and affinity makes sure the pod ends up on the node with GPU). I run the task as a KubernetesPodOperator. I don't think either this is Airflow specific.

Comment: @talonmies, I thought the same at first, however as I specified in the post, the GPU used on Kubernetes is the same used on Google Colab (where the code runs without any issues). Looking at PyTorch Dockerfile of version 1.4.0, this is also confirmed by [TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7f73f1d591afba823daa4a99a939217fb54d7688/docker/pytorch/Dockerfile#L28)